# Display every PDF page content into distinct divs

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf

I have a book called **php_5_for_dummies.pdf**. 
The total page count of it is 5. 
I want to display every PDF page content in distinct divs.

> Example: it should be displayed like this:

1. `<div class='1'>Content of pdf page 1 </div>`
2. `<div class='2'>Content of pdf page 2 </div>`
3. `<div class='3'>Content of pdf page 3 </div>`
4. `<div class='4'>Content of pdf page 4 </div>`
5. `<div class='5'>Content of pdf page 5 </div>`

This is so far i have done.

```
function pdf_page_no($filepath){
    $fp = @fopen(preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]/i", "",$filepath),"r");
    $max=0;
    while(!feof($fp)) {
        $line = fgets($fp,255);
        if (preg_match('/\/Count [0-9]+/', $line, $matches)){
            preg_match('/[0-9]+/',$matches[0], $matches2);
            if ($max<$matches2[0]) $max=$matches2[0];
        }
     }
    fclose($fp);
    if($max==0){
        $im = new imagick($filepath);
        $max=$im->getNumberImages();
    }

    return $max;
}

$filename = "php_5_for_dummies.pdf";
$total_page_no  = pdf_page_no($filename);

for ( $i=0 ; $i >= $total_page_no; $i++ ) {

    echo "<div class='{$i}'>";
       // here should display the content from page 1 of pdf
    echo "</div>";

}
```

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: i am just able to extract page no. from pdf

Comment: Code that you tried can you share?

Comment: i have added my code so far i have done.

Comment: NO !  i am only able to display page no and loop pages not the content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDF is not a native web format in the same way as HTML, SVG or the typical image formats (JPG, PNG, TIF, etc.). Display of PDFs is browser-dependent and typically a "full page" item, not an element of a page like a <div>. Depending on the browser configuration, PDFs are sometimes not displayed inside the browser at all - e.g., I configure my browsers to open PDFs using Adobe Reader outside of the browser in order to provide more options, better quality printing, etc. The opposite is also a problem - typical HTML pages don't print well and the solution is to convert to PDF for consistent WYSIWYG printing. But most web sites don't do that because there is no easy way without a lot of programming. Anyone who can truly solve the underlying problems will make a fortune. Well, actually probably not make much money at all as so much software is effectively free, but I digress...

Solutions that I have seen:

a) Convert the PDF pages to graphic images. You can do this using the ImageMagick convert program. Then display an <img> inside each <div>. The downside is that resolution is limited to the image size instead of being a full scalable (and easily printable) PDF page. I have done this for previews with the image clickthrough generating a browser-dependent download/display of the actual PDF.

b) Frame a page which contains the PDF. I believe I have seen this on some utility bill web sites. Inside the frame the page is treated as a full page so if the browser supports internal PDF viewing then this will work.